# piping with error checking using subprocess in python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, pipe

I have a piping scheme using `subprocess` where one process `p2` takes the output of another process `p1` as input:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("ls -al", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("grep mytext - ", shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p2.communicate()
```

`p1` or `p2` could fail for various reasons, like wrong inputs or malformed commands.

This code works fine when `p1` does not fail. How can I do this but also check whether `p1` specifically or `p2` specifically failed? Example:

```
# p1 will fail since notafile does not exist
p1 = subprocess.Popen("ls notafile", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("grep mytext - ", shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p2.communicate()
```

I can check `p2.returncode` and see that it's not `0`, but that could mean that `p2` failed or p1 failed. How can I specifically check whether `p1` failed or `p2` failed in cases where this pipe goes wrong?

I don't see how I can use `p1.returncode` for this which would be the ideal and obvious solution. ex:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("ls foo", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("grep mytext - ", shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# here, p2.returncode not defined yet since we didn't communicate()
assert(p2 is None)
r = p2.communicate()
# now p2 has a returncode
assert(p2.returncode is not None)
# ... but p1 does not!
assert(p1.returncode is None)
```

so I don't see how returncode helps here?

The full solution thanks to @abarnert is something like this:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("ls -al", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("grep mytext - ", shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p2.communicate()
if p2.returncode != 0:
  # something failed
  if p1.wait() != 0:
     # p1 failed...
  else: 
     # p2 failed...
```

p.s. I know the caveats of `shell=True` for security.

Comment: Forget about the caveats of `shell=True` for security for a moment; it also makes things more complicated, because you're not actually piping `ls` to `grep` at all; you're piping one `sh` to another `sh`. Is there a reason you're doing that?

Comment: in my application `ls` and `grep` are more interesting command line programs (which use shell features in file input etc so need `shell=True`). what's wrong with the above way of doing it? i'm piping the output of ls from shell to grep, which achieves the right result of grepping the output of ls

Comment: Also, `result` doesn't have a `returncode`; it's `p1` and `p2` that do.

Comment: @abarnet: yes that was typo, fixed

Comment: But that's almost your whole answer. `p1.returncode` is what you want. Except that, because you're sticking extra processes in the middle, if `p2` quits early you may need an explicit `wait`. See my answer, which tries to explain in more detail.

Comment: A couple of problems remain. (1) call p1.wait() even if p2 succeeds because that clears the zombie process from the process table. (2) if p1 writes too much to stderr, it will hang because you aren't reading it. Look at the Popen.communicate code and see how it creates theads to read pipes and do that yourself for p1.stderr.

Comment: Adding on to tdelaney's points: If it's possible for `p2` to succeed even though `p1` failed (which it often is), you may want to do something with that case. Meanwhile, when looking at the source, look at the [3.3 (or any 3.2+) version of `communicate`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/subprocess.py), or the [backport to 2.4+](http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/), because there are edge cases the older version doesn't handle properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can check result.returncode and see that it's not 0, but that could mean that p2 fail.

No, you can't; `result` is just a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`.

It's the `Popen` objects that have `returncode` values.

And that's your answer here:

> How can I specifically check whether p1 failed or p2 failed in cases where this pipe goes wrong?

Just check `p1.returncode`.

However, be aware that while `p2.communicate` *does* guarantee that `p2` has been `wait`ed on, it does *not* guarantee the same for `p1`. Fortunately, it *should* guarantee that `p1` is at least `wait`able, it not `wait`ed, so:

```
if p2.returncode:
    if p1.wait():
        # p2 failed, probably because p1 failed
    else:
        # p2 failed for some other reason
```

Except that you almost definitely want to do a `p1.stdout.close()` right before the `communicate`. Otherwise, it's possible for an error in process 2 to leave process 1 blocked, and therefore your `p1.wait()` could block forever. (You could work around that by using `p1.poll()` here and then killing it if it's not finished, but really, it's better to not create the problem than to work round it.)

One last thing: You've set `p1.stderr` to `subprocess.PIPE`, which never gets attached to anything, so it's also possible for process 1 to block trying to write to an overflowing stderr pipe. You may want to fix that as well.

Comment: returncode checking would be the ideal solution but I don't see how it would work, I edited my answer to reflect the problem. any thoughts? maybe I misunderstood your answer

Comment: @user248237dfsf: My answer already explains that. Did you actually try the code using `p1.wait()`?

Comment: @abarnet: I don't understand still sorry -- if I use wait(), I get the same result.  I setup p1,p2 and then do: `p2.wait()` which makes `p1.returncode` be `None` rather than a return code value

Comment: @user248237dfsf: Why would you expect `p2.wait()` to do anything? Process 2 has already been `wait`ed by `communicate`, and you already have its return code. It's process 1 that may not have been reaped. Which is why I wrote `p1.wait()` in both the answer and the comment.

Comment: I think I understand now I updated my answer. Final question: could you explain the stderr issue? I thought I'm passing both stdout and stderr of p1 into p2, so what could cause blocking? What does it "not attached to anything" mean?

Comment: @user248237dfsf: When creating p1 you have `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.  That creates a *new* pipe (different from the one created for `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`).  Someone or something must read the stderr data at some point if the pipe "fills up".  If no one reads it, you can throw away the data but only as long as the pipe did not fill up completely.  You probably want to not set p1's stderr at all, or possibly, send it through the stdout pipe (a la `foo 2>&1 | bar` in sh).  To do the latter, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.